# sql query to check multiple data appear on different fields for multiple times

Tags: mysql, sql

lets say i have a table that logs login dates, with columns date & username

```
| Date  | Username  |
---------------------
| 09/10 | a         |
| 09/10 | b         |
| 09/10 | c         |
| 10/10 | b         |
| 10/10 | c         |
| 11/10 | c         |
| 11/10 | a         |
| 12/10 | b         |
| 12/10 | c         |
| 13/10 | a         |
| 13/10 | c         |
| 14/10 | a         |
| 14/10 | b         |
| 14/10 | c         |
| 15/10 | a         |
| 15/10 | b         |
| 16/10 | a         |
| 16/10 | b         |
| 16/10 | c         |
```

can i know how do I make a query that tell me how many times a certain set (at least 2) of same users log in together on the same day

results should tell me that:
eg.  user a b and c logged in together in 3 dates (9th, 14th, 16th), user a and c logged in together in (9th, 11th, 13th, 14th, 16th), user b & c.... and so on

Answer (score 0):

you could do somnething like:

```
Select count(username)
form yourTable
where yourDate between 2011/02/25 and 2011/02/27
```

Comment: hi, i thought of that but it doesnt tell me who log in with who, i also need all possible combination of users to be checked, i dont need the dates in result though, just the count will be fine

Answer (score 0):

**[Here is SQLFiddel Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13ba8/4)**

**Below is the Sample Which You can try :**

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`Date` varchar(5), `Username` varchar(1))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`Date`, `Username`)
VALUES
    ('09/10', 'a'),
    ('09/10', 'b'),
    ('09/10', 'c'),
    ('10/10', 'b'),
    ('10/10', 'c'),
    ('11/10', 'c'),
    ('11/10', 'a'),
    ('12/10', 'b'),
    ('12/10', 'c'),
    ('13/10', 'a'),
    ('13/10', 'c'),
    ('14/10', 'a'),
    ('14/10', 'b'),
    ('14/10', 'c'),
    ('15/10', 'a'),
    ('15/10', 'b'),
    ('16/10', 'a'),
    ('16/10', 'b'),
    ('16/10', 'c')
;

Create View V_Table1 as
select  * from Table1 order by date,username;

select groups,group_concat(date) as dates
 from  (
select date,group_concat(username) groups
  from V_Table1 T
 Group BY date
) T2
group by groups
order by groups
```

Answer (score 0):

The `GROUP BY` is your friend here:

```
SELECT `date`, GROUP_CONCAT(username)
  FROM logins
GROUP BY `date`
HAVING COUNT(username) > 1;
```

In other words: group them by date and print them. In this case, the `HAVING` will remove any login dates that just have a single user (you didn't have any in your sample data though).